# Zoom Meeting - Access to a meeting who are registered to my application

Tags: zoom-sdk, zoom-meeting

I have developed a App for teaching purpose. So I want users to attend a zoom meeting who has paid for course. So how can I disable the other users to attend the same meeting? So the flow is, user will click on one button on my app, and they will  be redirect to zoom client (On web, Android and iOS) and join the meeting. So how can I achieve this?

Tried all zoom SSO.